# How to put a Table View Controller within a Collection View Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

So basically I have a UICollectionView completely set up.  I have been trying to insert a Table View into it but unsuccessfully.  I have tried using a container view but Xcode called that an illegal declaration.  I have tried programmatically to add a TableView within my Custom Cell Class but when it does not let me inherit from UITableViewData Source.  I could simply put a TableView in my Cell in storyboard but then I am not sure how I would control it programmatically (i.e. Data Source and Delegate).  Any help at all would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What class do you want to have as the data source?  Are there a number of cells (>1) that each need tables with different data sources?

Comment: @PhillipMills So from a database I am getting an array that contains many arrays with Strings in each of them.  In each collection view cell I want to display a different array from the large array, each table cell containing one of the strings.  So I only really need on Data Source I think.  I was under the impression that if I created the TableView programmatically in the  Custom Cell Class then that had to be the Delegate and Data Source for that TableView.

Comment: Anything with a reference to the table can declare itself the datasource.  Without knowing your structure, this may be a bad example but: you could possibly have the view controller that is the datasource/delegate for the collection view also do it for the tables.  Each time it produces a cell or view for the collection, it can find the embedded table by tag and set itself as the datasource...or set some other object as the datasource.

Comment: @PhillipMills The problem I face with that structure is that the view controller that is the datasource/delegate for the CollectionView is of type CollectionViewController, so when I try to make it inherit from UITableViewDataSource, it says the ViewController does not conform to that protocol.

Comment: I suspect that just means that you haven't added the methods yet that the protocol requires.  (You don't actually **inherit** from `UITableViewDataSource`, just declare that you implement it in the class and then create that implementation.)